# How to change the date format in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, date

How to change the date format in c#,i am retrieving the information from database,in database the date format its stored in "dd/mm/yyyy",but when i getting this date to my form,its showing error,the string is not a valid datetime format. for eg "2/13/2014" while i getting error when i retrieving this date,i have tried this code

```
 string orderd = row.Cells[1].Value.ToString();
                    DateTime dt = Convert.ToDateTime(lbl_date.Text);
                     DateTime orderdt = Convert.ToDateTime(orderd);
```

how to convert this date while retrieving.,

```
  string orderd = row.Cells[1].Value.ToString();
   DateTime orderdt = Convert.ToDateTime(orderd);
```

this code also grtting error,the row.cells[1].value is that i am getting the value from gridview,then i am converting into datetime.,but the showing "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime."

Comment: What is the column type in DB? `Date`? or `varchar`?

Comment: Try putting Convert.ToDateTime( [value here]);

Comment: Your code has `-` while the samples have `-` in.

Comment: "2/13/2014" is "mm/dd/yyyy", not a "dd/mm/yyyy"

Comment: Note that if you've got a date or datetime field in the database, you shouldn't need to do any parsing at all.

Comment: @JonSkeet I hear alarm bells ringing when someone tells me that the date "ist stored in XYZ format" in the database...

Comment: @doctorlove At least one of your `-`s should be a `/`...

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar: Ditto. I'm hoping we get a response to Sriram's question...

Comment: i am getting from string to datetime.,the retreiving table the column type is varchar,when i am saving table column type is date

Comment: @Sarvan: That doesn't make sense to me: either the column type is varchar or it's datetime; it can't be both. (Unless you're copying from one table to another?)

Comment: @Jon Skeet:i am using the datatype as date,my team met using the data type as varchar,while integretaing the forms we are facing the isuues.,how to overcome this.,

Comment: That doesn't tell us anything about what the database is using. Are there multiple database columns involved here, or just one? If it's just one column in one table in one database, then it's either varchar or it's not - it doesn't matter whether it's you or another team member using it.

Comment: @Jon:WE both are sharing the single database,but using different tables,

Comment: Okay. That was *very* unclear from your previous comments. I suggest you edit that into the question - but then persuade the team using the varchar column that if they're trying to store datetime values, they use a datetime column.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a date string in the format of `dd/MM/yyyy` then it's definitely *not* going to parse as `yyyy-MM-dd` so the error you see is correct.

I *think* what you are looking for is to parse the date in it's current format i.e.

```
DateTime orderdt = DateTime.ParseExact(orderd, "dd/MM/yyyy",
    System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

but *display* the date as `yyyy-MM-dd`

```
orderdt.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")
```

Comment: :The best overloaded method match for 'string.ToString(System.IFormatProvider)' has some invalid arguments-i am getting this error.,when i ma usinng  DateTime orderdt = orderd.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"); this code.,

Comment: @Sarvan after `ParseExact` `orderdt` should be a `DateTime`...not a `string`.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at MSDN. This documention includes many ways to format dates.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Yes, but ideally it shouldn't be required at all. See the comments in the question - it's worth removing unnecessary string conversions entirely, IMO.

Comment: Yes it is correct that if the column is a datetime type it is not required to convert it. However it must be a non-datetime column. That's why i thought that link might help him out.

Comment: I wouldn't assume that - people often end up calling `ToString` on perfectly good `DateTime` values, and then try to parse them :( And if the database field really is a varchar, I'd try to fix that first...

Comment: I agree with you. If the column is varchar i agree also change that because it is bad design. But some people does not have the same experience with software development, so they take one step at the time. That's why i also posted that link instead of just writing a answer. The link contains much more information than "parsing and converting Datetime values". Hope you understand me.

Comment: Rather than just providing a link, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and just provide the link for additional reference. If you're not up to this task, you should consider simply [leaving a comment](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment) on the question instead of posting an answer.